# How to create react view which can handle database changes

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to use react to create views but my view requires data to be sent to database for update. How should I proceed with react in order to update database

Answer (score 1):

React is for creating front-end views so it doesn't natively do anything to do with database interaction. But you can send your data to the server with an AJAX request, using normal Javascript, jQuery, Backbone etc.

The [React tutorial section on updating state](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#updating-state) has an example of using jQuery to fetch data using ajax. A similar approach will work for writing data, too.